# C# Generics syntax help

Tags: c#, generics

I can't figure out the correct sytax for the following:

```
public interface IRepository<T,E> where T E: class
```

Looked a lot online, but articles don't seem to cover two classes.

Thank you

Comment: When in the future you have further questions about language syntax I encourage you to consult the specification. Your question here is answered in section 10.1.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the "Constraining Multiple Parameters" section of [Constraints on Type Parameters (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public interface IRepository<T, E> 
    where T : class
    where E : class
```

Comment: Thank you, i was trying to do where T,E: class

Answer (score 4):

```
public interface IRepository<T,E> 
where T: class
where E: class
```